# The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec: Exception: Invalid image data

Tags: image, flutter, dart, exception

Trying to fetch ***Tradingview*** Image but getting this error.

Is their another method to fetch ***Tradingview Images***.
\

> I want to display  [TradingView image](https://www.tradingview.com/x/ag1X9C1z/).

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                'https://www.tradingview.com/x/ag1X9C1z',
                scale: 1,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://www.tradingview.com/x/ag1X9C1z/',
              scale: 1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wD6e.png) 
[Invalid Image Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21RCH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Please check Your url. you can try to other url and check it.

```
 Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
            scale: 1,
          ),
```

Comment: other links are working perfectly fine, only error causing by TreadingView.com screenshots that I want to load, i am not getting any alternative for tradingview.com screenshot urls... :-(

Comment: You try to take a screenshot and put in assets folder and fetch image.

Comment: Your comment actually doesn't meet the need of the OP. His issue is to fetch from the said link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tradingview URLs you have link to an HTML page that contains the image, rather than the image itself.

Your image link (which is actually HTML): `https://www.tradingview.com/x/ag1X9C1z/`
contains the actual image: `https://s3.tradingview.com/snapshots/a/ag1X9C1z.png`

So I think you need to change your URL to `https://s3.tradingview.com/snapshots/a/ag1X9C1z.png`